# Structuring html links

Tags: html, directory, href

I'm working on my site on localhost. I have my directories as follows:
My ***index page*** is located directly in the site folder as such: 
`../htdocs > mysite > index.php` 
My **our-profile page** is located in sub-folder called about us as such:
`../htdocs > mysite > about-us > our-profile.php`

I have a link on the our-profile.php page that should link back to the homepage like this: 
 `<a href=..\index.php>Home</a>`.
But i keep getting a 404 - Not Found error. It uses the about-us directory as the root. So the link above tries to search for :
 `http://localhost:8888//mysite/about-us/mysite/index.php` 
instead of 
`http://localhost:8888//mysite/index.php`

How do i re-structure the links?.

**EDIT:**
I'm working with dreamweaver. Could it be an issue from dreamweaver?

Comment: Did you try `<a href=..\..\index.php>Home</a>`?

Comment: I just did.. stil gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using backslashes, use forward slashes

```
<a href=../index.php>Home</a>.
```

Comment: is there a hyphen in the folder name in my-site or is that a typo ?

Comment: so it's searching for `mysite/about-us/mysite/index.php` without the hyphen in my-site, something is defo wrong.first thing is make a file called test.html with just <h3>test<h3> in and stick it in the about-us folder and link to that in the our-profile.php like <a href="test.html">Test</a>. Does it work ???

Comment: how do you add the links ? typed directly in or via a button in dreamweaver ? when you view the source of the page what does the link href say ?

Comment: I'm so sorry. The hyphen in my-site was infact a typo. I misread your comment. Just stressed out with this. However, i created the test file and linked it and it does work that way.                                                                       The links are typed directly as with all of my code. I'm not using design view.

Comment: never used dreamweaver so don't know what design view is....move test.html up a level and add ../ to the front of the href like `<a href="../test.html">Test</a>`. now does it work ?

Comment: wow yes it works now..What just happened? because index.php is also in the thesame directory now as test.html

Comment: Glad it all works, don't forget to mark the answer.not 100% sure why it didn't work before, doesn't matter now if it works,just keep an eye when doing links to always use forward slashes and double check paths.Billy